# Want to Running NodePort on localhost Kube Services

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am trying to run the kubernetes service via NodePort.

[image: This is my node.js running]

[image: This is my deployment file]

[image: This is my service file]

[image: Pods]

[image: Deployment running]

[image: Services running]

[image: Description of service running]

[image]

I can't figure out what the problem is when i try to hit `localhost:31553` on my device it is not listening there. Moreover I also tried with `10.101.184.102:31553` it also doesn't work.
I want to run it on localhost.
Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are running locally you can use port-forwarding:

```
kubectl port-forward -n default service/posts-srv 4000:4000
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can't we access the port without forwarding it.

Answer (score 4):

`10.101.184.102` is an IP within your SDN, you probably can't reach it from your workstation. It won't be listening on your loopback either (`localhost`). You need to connect to one of your Kubernetes nodes IP address, within your LAN, on the TCP port allocated to your NodePort Service. Eg:

```
$ kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME       STATUS                     ROLES    AGE    VERSION   INTERNAL-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                       KERNEL-VERSION    CONTAINER-RUNTIME
compute1   Ready                      worker   243d   v1.18.3   10.42.253.20   <none>        Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)   4.19.0-10-amd64   containerd://1.2.13
....
$ curl http://10.42.253.20:31553
```

If running in some cloud-integrated Kubernetes, you'ld rather use the LoadBalancer Service type (see [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/)).

Answer (score 2):

When you are using `NodePort` service you need to access the service via node's ip address. Note that this Service is visible as `<NodeIP>:spec.ports[*].nodePort`. So, the template is like `<node-ip>:<node-port>` . for getting the node ip you can run the command .

```
$ kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME                 STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE       KERNEL-VERSION     CONTAINER-RUNTIME

kind-control-plane   Ready    master   32d   v1.18.2   172.18.0.2    <none>        Ubuntu 19.10   5.8.0-38-generic   containerd://1.3.3-14-g449e9269
```

here your  nodeport is `31553`.

now try curl : `curl -k 172.18.0.2:31553`

and it's always better if you set the `spec.ports[*].nodePort` value, otherwise it will be a random port from range of `30000-32767`.

**service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: posts-srv
  labels:
    app: posts
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 4000
    protocol: TCP
    name: posts
    targetPort: 4000
    nodePort: 31553
  selector:
    app: posts
```

Answer (score 1):

```
kubectl port-forward <pod_name> 8080:4000
```

and go at `localhost:8000`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can't we access the port without forwarding it.

Comment: @AnuragGupta Try setting the containerPort in deployment.yaml and then try this could solve your issue.

Comment: @AnuragGupta could you please add the output of ```kubectl describe po <pod_name>```

Comment: Added the output

Answer (score 0):

When Resetting the Kubernetes Cluster on Docker Desktop, it doesn't free already used ports. Try to change the port number for the one you haven't  used yet and redeploy your app.